# EKS configuration: API Gateway and pods in private subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, eksctl

In **AWS**, I'm trying to configure my **K8S** cluster with **EKS**, and from my limited experience with **AWS** and its services, I am struggling in configuring the integration between different parts.

Context:

- Created the cluster with `eksctl` tool (the **VPC**, subnets and **NAT Gateway** were created automatically by `eksctl`).
- Created two **node groups** (also with `eksctl`), one in private subnet and another one in public subnet.
- Created a **deployment** for my backend application (deploying it to the **private subnet**):

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-dev-deployment
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-dev
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        subnet-type: private
      containers:
        - name: api-dev
          image: [my private image URL from ECR]
          ports:
              - containerPort: 5000
```

The pod deployment is **OK**, and it's able to connect to the internet from the private subnet (connection to `mongodb atlas` in my case), so **NAT Gateway** is working fine here.

What I am trying to achieve:

- Configure **API Gateway** so it can send requests to the application deployed in the pod inside the **private subnet**.

What I did:

- Created an API in the **API Gateway** service, created the resource `/status` (the health check endpoint from my application) with GET method.
- In the request integration, I have chosen `HTTP` as integration type and I've set the value `http://192.168.98.28:5000/status` as the endpoint **URL** (`192.168.98.28` is the internal **IP** of my pod in private network, got it with `kubectl`: `kubectl get pods -o wide`)

What's going wrong:

When I am trying to do a test call to the **API Gateway** endpoint, I am getting an error **500** with the message:

> Sat Aug 05 16:33:18 UTC 2023 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address.

Can please anyone help me in configuring the above mentioned? I was going through much documentation, but I can't find a good one.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to get response from pod directly without `service`. When you create a service to expose a deployment, it will spin up an aws loadbalancer. You will get response from that loadbalancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first of all you need service type Loadbalancer to expose your pod, I also think that both API Gateway and EKS cluster are in different VPCs, so it is not possible to connect them without VPC endpoints

So the external traffic will be routed via API Gateway which sends traffic to the services hosted inside EKS via VPC Private Link -> ELB.

Here is [a blog](https://antonputra.com/amazon/Integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/) for reference